# Submitting an ASP web form to TFS

Tags: asp-classic, tfs

I'm having an issue with integrating Team Foundation Server into our request form.

At the moment we have users submitting requests to a "work stack". Every time the team has to check for requests they have to log into the work stack to see them. We'd like to switch the form to submitting directly to TFS which would make it much easier to keep on track.

We currently develop in ASP using VS2010 so we're using TFS 2010 (due for an upgrade soon).

This is a code snippet we're currently experimenting with:

```
<% end if 'Session("EditWorkPackages") then %>
<div id="dDescription">
  <label class="30" for="Description">Description</label>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="70" name="Description" id="Description"><%= rsRequest("Description") %></textarea>
</div>
<div id="dDocPath">
  <label class="30" for="DocPath">Attachment</label>
  <span id="DocPath">
    <a href="<%= rsRequest("DocPath") %>" target="_blank"><%= rsRequest("DocPath") %></a>
  </span>
</div>
<div id="dTFSsend" align="center">
  <input type="button" name="SendToTFS" id="TFS_<%=rsRequest("RequestID")%>" value="Send to TFS" title="Send to TFS" onclick="DoReq('TFS', <%=rsRequest("RequestID")%>, '<%=rsRequest("RequestHashKey")%>', 6)" />
</div>
```

Which will send the request form.

Then we have code (another snippet) handling the AJAX:

```
if Request("RequestTypeID") = "1" then
  call RequestSetStatus(RequestID, RequesthashKey, 4, UserID)
elseif Request("RequestTypeID") = "2" then
  call RequestSetStatus(RequestID, RequesthashKey, 11, UserID)
'elseif Request("RequestTypeID") = "6" then
  ' // However you would invoke the TFS controller
end if
```

I've already found some pages trying to help but they assume the web form is in C#, which ours isn't.

We do have a backend handling TFS events, like logging whether it was successful, but we can remove it if that becomes redundant.

What am I doing wrong?
Edit: Do I have to point out this code doesn't work and that I don't know how to implement passing the form/field data to TFS? I thought it was obvious that the code isn't right.

Comment: One thing you're doing wrong is to use Classic ASP instead of ASP.NET. You know that "Classic" ASP is obsolete, don't you?

Comment: I have no control over that, that's the way it was written back in the IE7 days. There are plans to use ASP.NET but there's no timeframe AFAIK.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I've been asked to add a button which sends the request form to TFS. I've been told there's a (working) backend for logging TFS events, etc. but whatever the case we don't want to use this "workstack" for adding/checking requests. TFS would make it far easier.

Comment: As far as i know, TFS has no ability to receive a form.

Comment: The idea is to get the field data and send it to TFS. I'm more than aware TFS can't receive forms as they are.

Comment: You keep asking what you're doing wrong, but you haven't told us what problem you're having. At any rate, see [Team Foundation Server SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa398956.aspx).

Comment: I know Classic ASP well, I don't know TFS at all, but from what I've read it uses SQL Server databases.  If it can't accept form/querystring data then you may need to look at getting your ASP pages to talk to the database directly, and you should be able to find plenty of tutorials on how to do that.  I think it's wrong to say Classic ASP is obsolete.  Dated yes, but it isn't obsolete as long as the current IIS version supports it, which it does